# How do I resolve synciwam.vbs error 1B6?

Tags: asp.net, permissions, iis-6

I'm trying to migrate a website from Windows 2000 to Win2k3 using the IIS 6 Migration Tool.  I'm getting a bunch of 404s on content.  A popular theory is that my IWAM account is out of sync with the IIS metabase, and to run synciwam to fix it.  However I'm getting this 1B6 error and the only link I haven't chased in google (that's obvious to me) is Experts Exchange...

Here's the results of running that script:

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>cscript synciwam.vbs -v
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.


IIS Applications Defined:
Name, AppIsolated, Package ID
Root, 0,
Root, 0,
Root, 1, {27EE9424-034E-46C6-8635-433B8DF0293A}
PMA-Search, 2, {27EE9424-034E-46C6-8635-433B8DF0293A}
BCC, 2, {27EE9424-034E-46C6-8635-433B8DF0293A}
fmweb, 2, {27EE9424-034E-46C6-8635-433B8DF0293A}

Out of process applications defined:

Count: 28
{3D14228D-FBE1-11d0-995D-00C04FD919C1}
{27EE9424-034E-46C6-8635-433B8DF0293A}


Error: 1B6: Object doesn't support this property or method
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never answered this question, but I did solve my problem.  I'm not even sure if it had to do with the IWAM account or not.

Scenario:

Moving from Win2k/IIS5 to Win2k3/IIS6
A bunch of classic ASP and ASP.NET 1.1 apps
Using the IIS 6 Migration Toolkit

Only images got served.  Not htm files, not asp.

Solution:
I saw a bunch of posts talking about dynamic content and enabling them in web extensions (and I did that).  Still no dice.

I thought I needed to enable SSI because one of the htm files I was looking at was using includes.

In doing so I *may have* introduced a new file mapping for .htm to ssi.dll

Remove this mapping and I started serving htm pages.

Problem 2 was ASP pages not being displayed.  Turns out (I think) that the migration tool has the path to asp.dll as WINNT\System32 and that's an invalid path on Windows 2003, it should be WINDOWS\System32